# unable to install textacy in python 3.0

Tags: python, anaconda, nlp, textacy

I am trying to install textacy to perform NLP tasks, but getting an error while trying to do:

pip install textacy

in Anaconda prompt.
The error I am getting is

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Please suggest how to overcome this as same issue i am facing with many other python libraries as well.